# Hahn's Lemma in Royden

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading through Royden, 3rd and 4th editions, and must be having a terrible day in terms of absolute convergence. I cannot for the life of me recall why the $m_k \rightarrow \infty$. This is page 273 for 3rd edition, also they are $n_k$ in that edition, or page 344 in the 4th edition. I understand that $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \nu(E_k)$ is convergent since $\nu(E) = \nu(A) + \sum^\infty_{k=1} \nu(E_k)$ and $\nu(E) < \infty$. I also see that since each $\nu(E_k) < -\dfrac{1}{m_k}$ we have

$
\sum^\infty_{k=1} \nu(E_k) < \sum^\infty_{k=1} -\dfrac{1}{m_k}
$

I know this is surely an answered in 5 seconds question. Thank you in advance for helping me with my blindness.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, upon further reading, correct me if I am wrong, but since $\nu(E_k)\leq 0$ for all $k$, then this is just the same as if I had it written the other direction for $\nu(E_k) \geq 0$ for all $k$:

$
\infty > \sum^\infty_{k=1} \nu(E_k) \geq \sum^\infty_{k=1} \dfrac{1}{m_k}
$

Thus, the $m_k \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|v(E)|< \infty$
$$\Rightarrow -\infty< v\left(\bigcup E_k\right)=\sum v(E_k)\le \sum\frac{-1}{m_k}$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum \frac{1}{m_k} < +\infty,$$

So $\lim \frac{1}{m_k}=0$ and thus $\lim m_k= \infty$.